# Python dataclass evaluating type-hinted Dict fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, type-hinting, python-dataclasses

I am wondering what the right way to evaluate a python dataclass field type is? In particular, with Dict field types which have their key/values types specified in the dataclass; is there a way to evaluate the field's `.type` against a un-typed Dict (ie: catch all Dicts, regardless of key/value type)?

In the example below, a simple dataclass with two fields is created and type hinted.

```py
# -*- Python Version: 3.7 -*-
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, fields
from typing import Dict

@dataclass
class Example:
    attr_dict_a: Dict[str, int] = field(default_factory=dict)
    attr_dict_b: Dict[int, int] = field(default_factory=dict)
```

Then: is there a way to iterate over the fields and evaluate which field is a `Dict` type, but ignoring the key/value types?

```py
x = Example({"1":1}, {1:1})

# Try and evaluate field.type against an untyped Dict:
for field in fields(x):
    print(field.name, field.type, field.type == Dict)
# >>> attr_dict_a typing.Dict[str, int] False
# >>> attr_dict_b typing.Dict[int, int] False

# Try and evaluate field.type against a typed Dict:
for field in fields(x):
    print(field.name, field.type, field.type == Dict[str, int])
# >>> attr_dict_a typing.Dict[str, int] True #<----- Works if you specify the key/value types
# >>> attr_dict_b typing.Dict[int, int] False
```

If I would like to just do something each time I encounter any Dict (regardless of the key/value type-hints), what would be the proper way to do that evaluation?